# Is there a quicker way to generate integers which are hard to factor than multiplying two large primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, primality-test

An easy way to generate an integer which is hard to factor is to find two large primes and multiply them. As a bonus, you know the factors. I'm interested in whether it's possible to find integers (using a poly-time algorithm) which are very hard (takes more than poly-time) to factor, but using a quicker method and not necessarily deriving the prime factors.

[edit]

I'm aware of probabilistic primality tests. Nevertheless, I want a more efficient method than finding 2 primes and multiplying them.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by cheaper? If you are talking about algorithmic runtime, multiplying two numbers is hard to beat.

Comment: @MikePierce addressed in the edit. It's expensive to do that because you need to find two large primes. But... if you know quite a lot of large prime numbers then maybe you're right.

Comment: Have you looked into probabilistic primality testing? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Probabilistic_tests  (Aside: the word "possibly" in your question is rather misleading.)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: you were right. I've removed the stupid bit from my comment. I think the received wisdom in the cryptographic programming world would be that finding two high probability primes is fairly easy.

Comment: Virtually *any* large number is hard to factor, I'd say. As a bonus, you can trial-divide away all small primes to make even partial factorization harder. However, this makes it likely that the number has only few primes. If it *is* prime that *may* be easy to detect. If there are exactly two factors $p,q$ they *may* be in a relation that makes one of the well known factorization methods feasible (e.g., $p\approx q$ is a problem, as is $\frac pq\approx\text{simple fraction}$, as is $p-1$ can be factored, as is ...). *(continued)*

Comment: *(continuation)* In the end, to be confident that none of these exception spoils your work, finding two large primes (in appropriate relation) may be comforting while still being quite fast.

Comment: Does this number you want to generate _have_ to be composite?

Comment: @CSCFCEM Non-composite numbers are easy to factor, or at least certainly not "very hard'.

Comment: @ErickWong If you know they are non-composite, sure.  I was asking in the case that if the OP didn't care whether or not the number had to be factored, why not just generate a string a random integers and treat it as a large number (it _could_ be prime but knowing that could be hard just by looking at it).  I guess I just needed more context on what the OP was trying to accomplish.

Comment: See also http://www.graysage.com/djr/isp.txt, which is mentioned in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Semiprime.html.

Comment: @NaN hard "just by looking at it", I know there are algorithms for primality testing, but depending on how many digits you have in your integer wouldn't that get expensive (time-wise at least)?  When I read "multiplying two large primes" I imagine an integer with a fair amount of digits.  Could you clarify (roughly) how many digits in the integer you wish to generate?  That might help users come up with an accurate answer.  The method to generate a number to factor for a high school test would probably vary a lot from a number used in cryptography research (I would think anyway!!!).

Comment: Have you thought about a simple formula involving powers of primes? e.g., $\frac{97^n - 7^{n - 1}}{6}$? Take a formula like that to factordb.com and see if for small $n$ you get "CF" (stands for "incompletely factored numbers").

Comment: @CSCFCEM i can describe what i want asymptotically. i want a poly-time algorithm for the problem. this way, just generating a very large number is not enough, because if it takes poly-time and it's poly-large then testing primality should be poly-easy. so the answer to your question is no. anyway, i should clarify this point in the question.

Comment: If you do not know the prime factors of the resulting number, the second largest prime factor might be relatively small (Lets say,$<10^{30}$). In this case, the factorization of the number would not be hard enough. But multiplying, lets say $20$ distinct $200$-digit-primes will produce a number, which will be extremely hard to be factored. And $200$-digit-primes are very easy to find with today's software.